# Codeigniter3 sending email using SSL ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, fsockopen

I use Codeigniter3, wamp(php7, MySQL, Apache)
There was no problem before. I uncommented `extension = php_openssl.dll` line in the php.ini file. Now sending email displays the following error message:

```
1. Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL 
Error messages: error:14090086:SSL 
routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2055

2. Message: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2055

3. Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2055
```

and my email sending code:

```
    function mailConfig(){
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'user@gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['crlf'] = '\r\n';      //should be "\r\n"
        $config['newline'] = '\r\n';

        $this->load->library("email");
        $this->email->initialize($config);
    }

    /**
     * User: 김용식
     * 메일 전송
     */
    function sendmail($title, $message, $file_path){
        $this->mailConfig();

        $this->email->clear();
        $this->email->to("dydtlr19@gmail.com");
        $this->email->from("mail.stccorp@gmail.com");
        $this->email->subject($title);
        $this->email->message($message);
        if($file_path != ''){
            $this->email->attach($file_path);
        }
        if (!$this->email->send()){
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
//            echo "<script>alert(\"전송에 실패했습니다.\");</script>";
        } else{
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
//            echo "<script>alert(\"전송하였습니다.\");</script>";
        }
    }
```

Please help me out to resolve this problem.

Comment: You need to define the location of your SSL certificates in your PHP .ini file. http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.configuration.php You should be able to use http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem if you do not have one.

Comment: @fyrye Thanks! It Work!